# Filtering of RefNbr PXSelector on Expense Claim

Tags: acumatica

I need to customize the Expense Claim screen (EP301000) to do the following:

- Add user field as a checkbox to header section (Done)
- Use that checkbox value to filter the RefNbr PXSelector lookup to only show results for the Employee ID shown on the 'Claimed By' field.

Looking at the DAC for RefNbr, I don't see any normal PXSelector lookup that I'm used to seeing.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see the DACField is using an attribute **[EPExpenceClaimSelector]**

The definition of that is as below

```
public class EPExpenceClaimSelectorAttribute : PXSelectorAttribute
    {
        public EPExpenceClaimSelectorAttribute()
            : base(typeof(Search2<EPExpenseClaim.refNbr,
                    InnerJoin<EPEmployee, On<EPEmployee.bAccountID, Equal<EPExpenseClaim.employeeID>>>,
                    Where<EPExpenseClaim.createdByID, Equal<Current<AccessInfo.userID>>,
                         Or<EPEmployee.userID, Equal<Current<AccessInfo.userID>>, 
                         Or<EPEmployee.userID, OwnedUser<Current<AccessInfo.userID>>,
                         Or<EPExpenseClaim.noteID, Approver<Current<AccessInfo.userID>>,
                         Or<EPExpenseClaim.employeeID, WingmanUser<Current<AccessInfo.userID>>>>>>>, OrderBy<Desc<EPExpenseClaim.refNbr>>>)
                , typeof(EPExpenseClaim.docDate)
                , typeof(EPExpenseClaim.refNbr)
                , typeof(EPExpenseClaim.status)
                , typeof(EPExpenseClaim.docDesc)
                , typeof(EPExpenseClaim.curyDocBal)
                , typeof(EPExpenseClaim.curyID)
                , typeof(EPEmployee.acctName)
                , typeof(EPExpenseClaim.departmentID)
                )
        {
        }
    }
```

You can use the same approach to create an attribute of your own with additional condition and use it in your cache attached method to replace the default selector.

Comment: Thanks Hybridzz - I figured it out.  I used a PXCustomSelectorAttribute and used the GetRecords() method to choose between two selects based on the custom checkbox on the screen...